# create a new model or use the user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a rails application. If you have a User model and a post model and a user can post X number of times according to a plan.

Can I just modify the User object and add a plan_id to my user object or is it better to generate a new model called plan and associate it to a user?

Comment: is plan_id the number of times the user can create a post?

Comment: yes Vimsha it would correspond to a subscription in stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what informations you want to store for the plan.

In my opinion, you should add a Plan model and add an association.
In that case, you can store all important informations about the plan itself in a Plan and use it to show them on the pricing page, as well.

But i guess, there is no "right" or "wrong" answer, just favorites. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no good way to answer this without knowing specifics or the future.

- Might users end up having multiple plans?
- How frequently are the plans required?

A "user" is not a "plan". A user *has* a plan. There *should* be a plan model; how it is stored is a separate issue. It may not be worth over-thinking at this point, either.

Comment: A user only has one plan. A plan is required to save a post.

Comment: @Ayrad Then it just depends. If I was using a relational DB I'd keep it as a separate model unless that proved to be a bottleneck. If I was using a NoSQL database I'd keep it as an embedded document. If you need to search on the plan it should be indexed either way.